# What language is this loop written in?

Tags: function, loops, do-while

This looks like a do-while loop with odd syntax.
Can anyone identify a language?

```
While var1 == var2 do:
    thisFunction(parameter)
```

Comment: I think is more pseudo code unless you have more of the language context to make a decision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bash.

You can check what while loops look like in a bunch of languages at [while loop on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop)